# Split a pipe-delimited series, groupby a separate series, and return the counts of each split value in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given a dataframe with a pipe-delimited series:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1960, 1960, 1961, 1961, 1961],
                   'genre': ['Drama|Romance|Thriller',
                             'Spy|Mystery|Bio',
                             'Drama|Romance',
                             'Drama|Romance',
                             'Drama|Spy']})
```

Or in data format:

```
   year                   genre
0  1960  Drama|Romance|Thriller
1  1960         Spy|Mystery|Bio
2  1961           Drama|Romance
3  1961           Drama|Romance
4  1961               Drama|Spy
```

I can split the `genre` series with `str.split` (as demonstrated in many similar questions on SO).

But I would also like to group by the year and return the count of `Drama`, `Romance`, `Thriller`, and so on for each unique year in new columns.

My initial attempt:

```
df_split = df.groupby('year')['genre'].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('|', expand=True).reset_index(drop=True))
```

which returns

```
            0        1         2
year                            
1960 0  Drama  Romance  Thriller
     1    Spy  Mystery       Bio
1961 0  Drama  Romance       NaN
     1  Drama  Romance       NaN
     2  Drama      Spy       NaN
```

but then how to get the count of each unique genre in its own column, by year?

I can get the unique genres using

```
genres = pd.unique(df['genre'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack())
```

but am still unsure of how to get the genres as separate series, with their counts by year.

The final output I'd like is:

```
      Drama  Romance  Thriller  Spy  Mystery  Bio
1960      1        1         1    1        1    1
1961      3        2         0    1        0    0
```

where each unique genre is its own series, with its corresponding count by year.

This may also very well also be an X-Y problem. My end goal is to produce a percentage stacked-area chart. Assuming `df_split` has the required transformation, I'd like to do:

```
df_perc = df_split.divide(df_split.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

which returns

```
         Drama   Romance  Thriller       Spy   Mystery       Bio
1960  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667
1961  0.500000  0.333333  0.000000  0.166667  0.000000  0.000000
```

and then

```
plt.stackplot(df_perc.index, *[ts for col, ts in df_perc.iteritems()],
                               labels=df_perc.columns)
plt.gca().set_xticks(df_perc.index)
plt.margins(0)
plt.legend()
```

giving the output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get to your desired result using some simple reshaping and aggregation:

```
(df.assign(genre=df['genre'].str.split('|'))
   .explode('genre')
   .groupby('year')['genre']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack(fill_value=0))     
 
genre       Bio     Drama   Mystery   Romance       Spy  Thriller
year                                                             
1960   0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667
1961   0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.333333  0.166667  0.000000
```

From here you can finish up by plotting an area plot:

```
(df.assign(genre=df['genre'].str.split('|'))
   .explode('genre')
   .groupby('year')['genre']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .plot
   .area())
```

---

**How It Works**

Start by exploding your data across rows:

```
df.assign(genre=df['genre'].str.split('|')).explode('genre') 

   year     genre
0  1960     Drama
0  1960   Romance
0  1960  Thriller
1  1960       Spy
1  1960   Mystery
1  1960       Bio
2  1961     Drama
2  1961   Romance
3  1961     Drama
3  1961   Romance
4  1961     Drama
4  1961       Spy
```

Next, do a `groupby` and get the normalized count:

```
_.groupby('year')['genre'].value_counts(normalize=True)

year  genre   
1960  Bio         0.166667
      Drama       0.166667
      Mystery     0.166667
      Romance     0.166667
      Spy         0.166667
      Thriller    0.166667
1961  Drama       0.500000
      Romance     0.333333
      Spy         0.166667
Name: genre, dtype: float64
```

Next, unstack the result:

```
_.unstack(fill_value=0)

genre       Bio     Drama   Mystery   Romance       Spy  Thriller
year                                                             
1960   0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667
1961   0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.333333  0.166667  0.000000
```

Finally, plot with

```
_.plot.area()
```

Comment: Seems like exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately the VM I'm doing this in (in a Udacity course) seems like it has an older version of pandas that doesn't support `explode`... in any case, I may be able to just finish this on my own machine. Accepted though, the help is much appreciated.

Comment: @BigBen If explode doesn't work you can use get_dummies instead: `temp = df.drop('genre', 1).join(df.genre.str.get_dummies(sep='|')).groupby('year').sum() ; temp.div(temp.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.area(xticks=temp.index) ` try this.

Comment: Yes. `get_dummies` works. Again, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: It was also quite a good call to just use `.plot.area()` here... I was overcomplicating things.

Comment: @BigBen pandas already has most general plotting functions covered in their visualization library: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could re-arrange your data in the first place:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

data = """
1960  Drama|Romance|Thriller
1960         Spy|Mystery|Bio
1961           Drama|Romance
1961           Drama|Romance
1961               Drama|Spy
"""

# sort it first by year
lst = sorted((line.split() for line in data.split("\n") if line), key=lambda x: x[0])

# group it by year, expand the genres
result = {}
for key, values in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dct = defaultdict(int)
    for lst in values:
        for genre in lst[1].split("|"):
            dct[genre] += 1
    result[key] = dct

# feed it all to pandas
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index').fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Which would yield

```
      Drama  Romance  Thriller  Spy  Mystery  Bio
1960      1        1       1.0    1      1.0  1.0
1961      3        2       0.0    1      0.0  0.0
```